# Creating dll and lib from one project in the solution

Tags: visual-studio

dll project for which i want to create unit tests.
In order to run unit tests i need my test project to compile all dependencies and i don't want to add my cpp files to test project.

The solution is to add lib in references but i have no clue how should i compile my project as both dll and as lib. Is this even possible ? I suggest that could be easy with naked cmake/make.

What i could do is create another project with same files and build it as a .lib. I think this solution is very primitive and it will require me to add .cpp files to projects twice if i ever want to add something new. I would prefer a solution in which i could have only one project in solution and have it build .dll (a main component) and a .lib for UT project reference.

I know i could also make UT load my .dll and have that kind of dynamic linkage, but that would make it harder due the need of creation of dll wrapper to access those functions.

I also considered using batch build and have custom build configuration. But this will require me to batch build every time i want to run UTs. I'd rather have it chose automaticaly. Maybe if i set UT project to be build under custom configuration the dependency will also be build with custom config?

Does Visual Studio 2015 bring any simple solution to this problem?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419385.aspx#sameProject

Comment: I don't have such thing as Test Project under c++ and i can't find it in online templates

Comment: Use Help > About to find out what edition of VS you use.